# awesome_print not printing in glorious color multiline layout?

Tags: ruby, rubygems, irb, awesomeprint

I'm experiencing an issue wherein `awesome_print` is not displaying output in it's gorgeous colorized multiline format.  What I find most curious is that while the gem is installed:

```
$ gem install awesome_print                                                                                     
Successfully installed awesome_print-1.6.1
1 gem installed
```

It returns a `false` upon `require` in IRB:

```
>> require 'awesome_print'
false
```

Any idea as to what may be causing this?  I am not quite sure how to tackle this since gem installation seems to work fine and I can even use `ap "test"` in IRB with no error, **except there is no colorization or proper printing with multiple lines** and seems to simply fall back to some other method for printing.

No `~/.aprc` changes evoke any changes either.

Answer (score 1):

Pass the options `ap object, options = {:plain => false, :multiline  => true}` or you can add it to the config file.

create an ~/.irbc file with the following content

```
require "awesome_print"
AwesomePrint.irb!

:multiline  => true,   # Display in multiple lines.
:plain      => false
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error,although require was returning false but awesome print was working, try to print something using awesome_print(ap), like

```
ap data = {foo: "bar"}
```